# Store the values returned from multiple case statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My multiple case statement are returning correct values but i need to store them somewhere so that i can use them in next query in which i need a loop and use these values in calculations Please suggest

```
SELECT CASE WHEN v.JANORG  '0' THEN v.JANORG WHEN v.JANAREA  '0' THEN v.JANAREA ELSE p.JANORG END "JANORG",

 CASE WHEN v.FEBORG  '0' THEN v.FEBORG WHEN v.FEBAREA  '0' THEN v.FEBAREA ELSE p.FEBORG END  "FEBORG",

 CASE WHEN v.MARORG  '0' THEN v.MARORG WHEN v.MARAREA  '0' THEN v.MARAREA ELSE p.MARORG END  "MARORG",

 CASE WHEN v.APRORG  '0' THEN v.APRORG WHEN v.APRAREA  '0' THEN v.APRAREA ELSE p.APRORG END  "APRORG",

 CASE WHEN v.MAYORG  '0' THEN v.MAYORG WHEN v.MAYAREA  '0' THEN v.MAYAREA ELSE p.MAYORG END  "MAYORG",

 CASE WHEN v.JUNORG  '0' THEN v.JUNORG WHEN v.JUNAREA  '0' THEN v.JUNAREA ELSE p.JUNORG END  "JUNORG",

 CASE WHEN v.JULORG  '0' THEN v.JULORG WHEN v.JULAREA  '0' THEN v.JULAREA ELSE p.JULORG END  "JULORG",

 CASE WHEN v.AUGORG  '0' THEN v.AUGORG WHEN v.AUGAREA  '0' THEN v.AUGAREA ELSE p.AUGORG END  "AUGORG",

 CASE WHEN v.SEPORG  '0' THEN v.SEPORG WHEN v.SEPAREA  '0' THEN v.SEPAREA ELSE p.SEPORG END  "SEPORG",

 CASE WHEN v.OCTORG  '0' THEN v.OCTORG WHEN v.OCTAREA  '0' THEN v.OCTAREA ELSE p.OCTORG END  "OCTORG",

 CASE WHEN v.NOVORG  '0' THEN v.NOVORG WHEN v.NOVAREA  '0' THEN v.NOVAREA ELSE p.NOVORG END  "NOVORG",

 CASE WHEN v.DECORG  '0' THEN v.DECORG WHEN v.DECAREA  '0' THEN v.DECAREA ELSE p.DECORG END  "DECORG"    

FROM PRJFCAST v,SYSGEN_PROJ p
WHERE v.orgpt_id=3 and p.orgid=6416 and p.projid=18 and p.year=2017
```

Comment: I can add it in a temporary table but then i need to delete the records alongwith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store them in variables so that they can be accessed later in the process.

```
DECLARE @JANORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @FEBORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @MARORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @APRORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @MAYORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @JUNORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @JULORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @AUGORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @SEPORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @OCTORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @NOVORG as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @DECORG as Varchar(100)


SELECT 
@JANORG = CASE WHEN v.JANORG <> '0' THEN v.JANORG WHEN v.JANAREA <> '0' THEN v.JANAREA ELSE p.JANORG END,
@FEBORG = CASE WHEN v.FEBORG <> '0' THEN v.FEBORG WHEN v.FEBAREA <> '0' THEN v.FEBAREA ELSE p.FEBORG END,
@MARORG = CASE WHEN v.MARORG <> '0' THEN v.MARORG WHEN v.MARAREA <> '0' THEN v.MARAREA ELSE p.MARORG END,
@APRORG = CASE WHEN v.APRORG <> '0' THEN v.APRORG WHEN v.APRAREA <> '0' THEN v.APRAREA ELSE p.APRORG END,
@MAYORG = CASE WHEN v.MAYORG <> '0' THEN v.MAYORG WHEN v.MAYAREA <> '0' THEN v.MAYAREA ELSE p.MAYORG END,
@JUNORG = CASE WHEN v.JUNORG <> '0' THEN v.JUNORG WHEN v.JUNAREA <> '0' THEN v.JUNAREA ELSE p.JUNORG END,
@JULORG = CASE WHEN v.JULORG <> '0' THEN v.JULORG WHEN v.JULAREA <> '0' THEN v.JULAREA ELSE p.JULORG END,
@AUGORG = CASE WHEN v.AUGORG <> '0' THEN v.AUGORG WHEN v.AUGAREA <> '0' THEN v.AUGAREA ELSE p.AUGORG END,
@SEPORG = CASE WHEN v.SEPORG <> '0' THEN v.SEPORG WHEN v.SEPAREA <> '0' THEN v.SEPAREA ELSE p.SEPORG END,
@OCTORG = CASE WHEN v.OCTORG <> '0' THEN v.OCTORG WHEN v.OCTAREA <> '0' THEN v.OCTAREA ELSE p.OCTORG END,
@NOVORG = CASE WHEN v.NOVORG <> '0' THEN v.NOVORG WHEN v.NOVAREA <> '0' THEN v.NOVAREA ELSE p.NOVORG END,
@DECORG = CASE WHEN v.DECORG <> '0' THEN v.DECORG WHEN v.DECAREA <> '0' THEN v.DECAREA ELSE p.DECORG END
FROM PRJFCAST v,SYSGEN_PROJ p
WHERE v.orgpt_id=3 and p.orgid=6416 and p.projid=18 and p.year=2017
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot and next step is to use the above values returned by select query do you have any idea how will i perform the calculations : Example select empno from emplyee where empno=7 and this will return 100 rows so i need to use empno/janorg,empno/feborg and then store them in a variable

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Provide Code examples?

Comment: I am using the query : select bom.pk_ID as bomid , bom.component_name as bomname, bom.component_attachrate as bomrate , bomitem.itemqty as itemqty 
 from COMPONENT bom , ITEMS bomitem,#temp t with some where conditions and this query will return like 90 rows so i need to use them by applying formula (itemqty * bomrate * janorg)/100 for janorg and (itemqty * bomrate * feborg)/100 for feborg and store them in a different table which is system_item (janorg,feborg,so on)

Comment: janorg=janorg+(itemqty * bomrate * janorg)/100) This formula should run like 90 times in a loop so that i can get final value for janorg and same for feborg Finally  the total of janorg gets stored